How to Implement Authenticated WebSocket Connection in Flutter Web
Problem:
I'm developing a Flutter application that requires WebSocket authentication. The connection method differs between mobile and web platforms:

Mobile (Flutter Mobile): Works with WebSocket.connect() and custom headers
final webSocket = await WebSocket.connect(
  url,
  headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer acess_token'}
);

final channel = IOWebSocketChannel(webSocket);


Web (Flutter Web): Requires WebSocketChannel.connect(), which doesn't support custom headers
channel = WebSocketChannel.connect(url);



Since WebSocket.connect() does not work on Flutter web, I cannot provide the bearer token, but my websocket server requires authentication. In that case, what should I do?
Since WebSocket.connect() does not work on Flutter web, I cannot provide the bearer token, but my websocket server requires authentication. In that case, what should I do?
